# Using pptx in python, how can I replace text tagged Powerpoint charts using a data dictionary?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm trying to create a tagged powerpoint deck that I can use a dictionary to find and replace instances of tags, and I've been able to do that with the below code.

```
# Loop through each slide in the PowerPoint template
for slide in prs.slides:
    # Loop through each shape in the slide
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        # Check if the shape has a tag
        if shape.has_text_frame and shape.text_frame.text:
            tag = shape.text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].text.strip()
            # Check if the tag matches the first column in the input file
            if tag in df.iloc[:,0].values:
                # Get the row where the tag is found
                row_idx = df[df.iloc[:,0] == tag].index[0]
                # Get the corresponding value from the second column
                value = str(df.iloc[row_idx, 1])
                # Replace the placeholder with the corresponding value from the input file
                shape.text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].text = value
```

Now, I am trying to fill in text tags within charts. I think my issue is that my text tags are not going through as text. Using this code, my series.values in instances of text are 0s.

```
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_chart:
            chart = shape.chart
            for series in chart.series:
                for value in series.values:
                    print(value)
```

I know series.values makes everything numeric, but I can't figure out how to get it to recognize text. Any insight would be appreciated.

Again, my ultimate goal: iterate over an entire Powerpoint, find charts, replace tagged chart values using a dictionary.

Thank you!